# Rest API Token Based Authentication Mechanism with Swagger Not Working

Tags: rest, swagger, access-token, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am trying to make an API call with rest token based authentication from swagger. But at server side, I don't find token in the request. I tried the same API call with poster and swagger. In Poster it works fine but in swagger it doesn't.

Below is my JSON file which I am using to make API call with token:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: City
  description: City Information
  version: 1.0.0
host: '127.0.0.1:8090'
schemes:
  - http
basePath: /App
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /city/list:
    get:
      summary: city
      description:
        Show cities name and its attributes.

      security:
        - APIAuthKey: []

      responses:
        '200':
          description: An array of city
        default:
          description: Unexpected error

securityDefinitions:
  APIAuthKey:
    type: apiKey
    in: header
    name: X-AUTH-TOKEN
```

And this is how swagger sends request with **X-AUTH-TOKEN**:

[image]

But, when I use the same API call wit same parameters and **X-AUTH-TOKEN** in *Poster*, It works fine. Below, I have highlighted that how I send request with Poster:

[image]

Can anyone please suggest if I'm doing anything wrong or missing something? Why am I unable to send token with request correctly to fetch at server side in request header?

Comment: ! Have you got the answer for this question?